# YII Newbie questions

Tags: php, yii

I am testing an MVC framework to use in my project and i have few questions regarding the YII.

1. I have create a model using GII, I know from java the code generation suppose to be a helper and most of the time should not be modified, because you may want to regenrate in the future, how is that suppose to work here?
2. I have created a CRUD out of the model and it gave a nice gui for it, I want to keep the gui for the admin side but i want to do a different one for the user side, what is the approach here?
3. If i am deciding to use some ORM in my app, this means that i need to create a different model, and i see that the current model inherits from an other one... problem?

   **In general**
4. Which is suppose to be faster in terms of load, CI? or YII?
5. correct me If i am wrong but MVC architecture does not really gives you a way to be really OOP, like java. interfaces, inheritance and polymorphic, it is a nice way to build a nice app quickly, not more than that. I am saying that because your controllers and model are already inheriting some classes.

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears true OOP Java would suck at programing in a stateless environment.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Usually models work ok after generation and most of time there's no need to change anything. If you add a field in your database and you need to regenerate it, when you do that you have in gii what's the new code, so you can copy/paste. Usually you don't need to do that, when i add fields to a database I add those fields in the model "by hand". Very easy and quickly, trust me

2) use templates. Create a new template in your layout views, and assign it to the controllers of the front end with $this->layout = '//my//layout';

3) Yii AR implementation is enougth for me. Can't answer to this questions, but you should not have any problem.

4) Depends on what kind of app you are running. I have worked with CI and Yii, i prefer yii for developer time and for speed.

5) You are "right" with that point.

Comment: Thanks, regarding 2. I need a different controller as well? because using the crud that was generated, the delete is only for logged in users. I guess this login  needs to be replaced with my own logic, right?

Comment: No, you don't. In your component folder you have your base controller, that has a public variable called layout. You just have to override that variable in the actions of each controller that you need. You can use how many layouts as you want in the same controller. Just create the layouts and assign that layout in the controller's actions

Comment: Sorry, i forget the delete question. You have an accesRules method in your controller that defines which user has access to which action. You can override, customize, or build your own. For simple access systems, the default accessRules and login behavior is enough